# Change redirect_url by overriding a method of Django admin

Tags: python, django, methods, overriding, admin

I would like to change the url that we are redirected after saving any change on Django admin page. The url defaults to `127.0.0.1:8000` because of the reverse proxy setting between nginx and gunicorn, and I would like to change it to my domain, e.g. `mysite.com`.

Referring to [@Ber's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240631), I decided to override [response_change()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1084) method in admin.py I created under the django app directory as below but it does not work due to lack of knowledge.

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ModelAdmin(admin.options.ModelAdmin):
    def response_change(self, *args, **kwargs):
        redirect_url = 'mysite.com'

        super(ModelAdmin, self).response_change(*args, **kwargs)
```

How may I improve this code so it can work properly?

Comment: I would suggest fixing the nginx config instead,because you will run into other issues later on as well, e.g. redirects outside admin, see: http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html

Answer (score 0):

The result never returned, you can try like this:

```
default = super(ModelAdmin, self).response_change(*args, **kwargs)
default.redirect_url = 'mysite.com'
return default
```

Comment: Thanks, @shellbye. I amended the code to return as you advised, but the redirect url looks the same after saving changes on Django admin page. Maybe response_change() is not the one I am looking for?

Comment: I updated my answer and maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339845/redirect-on-admin-save) question will help you too.